# Can't create a Candlestick chart using MVC and System.Web.Helpers.Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, candlestick-chart

The code below uses the charting functionality in System.Web.Helpers.Chart. I am trying to create a candlestick chart where there are four y values (open, high, low, and close) for each x value (which would be a date).

I am getting this error with the code below: "Data points insertion error. Number of X values is less than Y values."

I feel like I have to define the number of y points or something... but I cannot find one example of a Stock or Candlestick that utilized the System.Web.Helpers.Chart library.

```
        var bytes = new Chart(width: 400, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: "Candlestick",
                xValue: new[] { "6/1/2016", "6/2/2016", "6/3/2016" },
                yValues: new[] { 100, 110, 95, 97, 100, 110, 95, 97, 100, 110, 95, 97, })                    
            .GetBytes("png");
```

**Update: The code below fixed the problem with the data series... but now I'm just getting lines as in the image below... and I'm not really sure which series are the open, high, low, and close.**

No matter what order I add the series I get pretty much this image... also it's the same whether I use Stock or Candlestick.

[image]

```
        var theme = @"
<Chart  BackColor=""White""
        BorderColor=""181, 64, 1""
        BorderWidth=""2"" 
        BorderlineDashStyle=""Solid"" 
        Palette=""BrightPastel"">
    <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea  Name=""Default"" 
                    _Template_=""All"" 
                    BackColor=""Transparent"" 
                    BackSecondaryColor=""White"" 
                    BorderColor=""Transparent""
                    BorderDashStyle=""Solid"" 
                    ShadowColor=""Transparent"">
            <AxisY LineColor=""Transparent"">
                <MajorGrid Interval=""Auto"" LineColor=""Transparent"" />
                <LabelStyle Font=""Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"" />
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX LineColor=""Transparent"">
                <MajorGrid LineColor=""Transparent"" />
                <LabelStyle Font=""Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"" />
            </AxisX>
            <Area3DStyle Inclination=""15"" IsClustered=""False"" IsRightAngleAxes=""False"" Perspective=""10"" Rotation=""10"" WallWidth=""0"" />
        </ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <Legend _Template_=""All"" Alignment=""Center"" BackColor=""Transparent"" Docking=""Bottom"" Font=""Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold"" IsTextAutoFit =""False"" LegendStyle=""Row"">
        </Legend>
    </Legends>
</Chart>";

        var chartType = "Stock";
        var xValue = new[] { "6/1/2016", "6/2/2016", "6/3/2016" };

        var bytes = new Chart(width: 400, height: 200, theme: theme)
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: chartType,
                xValue: xValue,
                yValues: new[] { 50, 50, 80 }
                )
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: chartType,
                xValue: xValue,
                yValues: new[] { 20, 130, 120 }
                )
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: chartType,
                xValue: xValue,
                yValues: new[] { 70, 230, 120 }
                )
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: chartType,
                xValue: xValue,
                yValues: new[] { 20, 70, 60 }
                )
            .GetBytes("png");
```

Comment: Wild guess only, but perhaps `yValues: new[] { new[] { 100, 110, 95, 97 }, new[] {100, 110, 95, 97 }, new[] { 100, 110, 95, 97 } };`

Comment: Reasonable guess (it had occurred to me)... but then I get the error; Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series.

Comment: Adding a series for each of the High/Open/Close/Low values generates the chart without errors - e.g.. `.AddSeries(chartType: "Candlestick", xValue: new[] { "6/1/2016", "6/2/2016" }, yValues: new[] { 100, 110 }).AddSeries(chartType: "Candlestick", xValue: new[] { "6/1/2016", "6/2/2016" }, yValues: new[] { 80, 90 }).AddSeries(.....`. But its not formatting correctly - just shows as 3 colored lines

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just figured that out myself... good find... not intuitive at all... but now... how to get more than just a vertical line!... I can't believe there is not one example anywhere from Microsoft on how to use Stock or Candlestick charts with this library!!!

Comment: I couldn't find any examples either. If I get some time later today I see if I can find the source code

Comment: The very first suggestion from @StephenMuecke is absolutely correct and would work with `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization`. I reckon this is a glitch with `System.Web.Helpers`. The `Candlestick` chart type expects 4 Y values per point, see [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456671.aspx). Therefore, throwing that _**Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series**_ exception must be a glitch.

Comment: I just ended up using OxyPlot.